# A function pointer issue. How to efficiently interface with C API (ie. GSL) from C++ class?

Tags: c++

This question seems to have been asked numerous times before, for example [here1](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=235922), [here2](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/657124-interface-problem) and [here3](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/10435/).

What I am trying to do is, set the member `function` of the C-Struct `gsl_function` to a member function of my class.

```
class MyClass{

    double foo(double x)
    {
        return ...;
    }

    double bar(double x)
    {
        ...
        gsl_function F;
        // Problem I cant do this (compiler error)
        F.function = &(this->foo);
    }
};
```

The third [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/10435/) above provides a solution, I think it is based on the wrapper approach described [here4](http://www.newty.de/fpt/callback.html#member).

So my question is can I do better. Is there an easier way? For example, possibly by using Boost's function and Bind objects.

I am weighing up the option of using a gsl wrapper, such as o2scl. But am a bit releuctant as I may pay the price later if the wrapper is not well maintained. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since GSL allows you to pass in arbitrary parameters, you can abuse this to hold the pointer to the instance under question.  Then use a static member function to forward to the member function:

```
class MyClass
{
    double foo(double x)
    {
       ...
    }
    static double foo_wrapper(double x, void *params)
    {
        return static_cast<MyClass*>(params)->foo(x);
    }

    double bar(double x)
    {
        ...
        gsl_function F;
        F.function=&MyClass::foo_wrapper;
        F.params=this;

        // invoke GSL function passing in F
        ...
    }
};
```

Can you do better?  Is there an easier way?  Not really.  Any approach you take will be doing this under the covers somewhere.

But you can write a simple wrapper which hides some of this:

```
class gsl_function_pp : public gsl_function
{
public:
    gsl_function_pp(boost::function<double(double)> const& func) : _func(func)
    {
        function=&gsl_function_pp::invoke;
        params=this;
    }
private:
    boost::function<double(double)> _func;

    static double invoke(double x, void *params)
    {
        return static_cast<gsl_function_pp*>(params)->_func(x);
    }
};
```

This should give you (possibly at a moderate performance penalty due to multiple indirections involved) the type of functionality you'd want:

```
class MyClass
{
    double foo(double x)
    {
        ...
    }

    double bar(double x)
    {
        gsl_function_pp F(boost::bind(&MyClass::foo, this, _1));
        // invoke GSL function passing in F
        ...
    }
};
```

The caveat is that you'll have to ensure that any `gsl_function_pp` object stays in scope for the entire time that the GSL might invoke it.  So, don't try to set up a root finder/etc in one function (using a local gsl_function_pp), return, and then perform root finding iterations in another -- you'll get a crash or worse.