# is there name hiding for void* params?

Tags: c++, pointers, gsl

I need to pass a member function to gsl_function, and used the wrapper described in this [link] ([A function pointer issue. How to efficiently interface with C API (ie. GSL) from C++ class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593726/a-function-pointer-issue-how-to-efficiently-interface-with-c-api-ie-gsl-from)). It worked, but I am a bit confused when trying to understand it. Basically there are three void* params that I labeled `ptr_par_0`, `ptr_par_1`, `ptr_par_2` in the code, it is obvious `ptr_par_0=patr_par_1` but they seem never get initialized in the code, is that true? `ptr_par_2` is indeed initialized to `*this`, but `ptr_par_0` & `ptr_par_1` are local variables of `foo_wrapper` function, so I think they should hide `ptr_par_2` and need their own initialization. I think there might be something I am unaware of, thanks in advance for clarification.

```
class MyClass
{
    double foo(double x)
    {
       ...
    }
    static double foo_wrapper(double x, void *params)   //ptr_par_0
    {
        return static_cast<MyClass*>(params)->foo(x);   //ptr_par_1
    }

    double bar(double x)
    {
        ...
        gsl_function F;
        F.function=&MyClass::foo_wrapper;
        F.params=this;                                  //ptr_par_2

        // invoke GSL function passing in F
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: ptr_par_0 is a function parameter. It is initialized when the function gets called.

Comment: GSL will call something like `F.function(x, F.params);` so `MyClass::foo_wrapper(x, this_from_bar)`.

Comment: If you're still learning C++, GSL is **way** too hard. And if you don't understand yet how function parameters are initialized, then you're definitely still learning C++.

Comment: Thank you Jarod42, right to the point! I found the  GSL_FN_EVAL(&F,x) calling method you pointed out. I would accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn comment into answer:

GSL will call something like `F.function(x, F.params);` (in `GSL_FN_EVAL(&F,x)`)

so `MyClass::foo_wrapper(x, this_from_bar)`

Comment: Thank you very much, Jarod42.